# How to the remove first slide in mobile version using bootstrap carousel for wordpress website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have created wordpress website and implemented bootstrap carousel there is no issue in this.

I want to hide the first slide using bootstrap carousel in the mobile version.
If i use jquery first() and eq() selector the entire slider is blank other sliders are not working. 
 I have added script but its not working please any on help me.

Reference Site: http://floretmedia.net/temp/sieger-parking-v2/

```js
if ($(document).width() < 995) {       
           $(".carousel-inner .carousel-item").find(".sieger-category").remove(); 
       
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner-wrapper">
    <div id="bootstrap-touch-slider" class="carousel bs-slider fade  control-round indicators-line" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" data-interval="4000">
       <div class="downarrow"><a href="#welcome"><img src="http://floretmedia.net/temp/sieger-parking-v2/wp-content/themes/seiger/theme/img/downarrow.png" class="img-fluid"></a> 
       </div>
      <!-- Wrapper For Slides -->
     <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
       <div class="carousel-item">
             <!-- Slide Text Layer -->
          <div class="slide-text slide_style_left">
             <h1 data-animation="animated zoomIn">
     <div id="sieger-banner"><strong>Parking System </strong>Swift the car to the flexible parking lot</div>
                  <div class="sieger-category">
                 <div class="row">
                  <a class="sieger-item" href="products/stack-parking-systems/"></p>
            <div class="sieger-img">
             <img src="http://192.168.1.156/sieger-parking/wp-content/themes/seiger/theme/img/stack-park.jpg" alt="stack parking" />
           </div>
          <div class="siger-txt">
            <p>STACK PARKING SYSTEM</p>
       </div>
       </a> <!-- sieger-item -->
      <a class="sieger-item" href="products/puzzle-parking-system/">
       <div class="sieger-img">
          <img src="http://192.168.1.156/sieger-parking/wp-content/themes/seiger/theme/img/puzzle-park.jpg" alt="puzzle parking" />
        </div>
      <div class="siger-txt">
        <p>PUZZLE PARKING SYSTEM</p>
       </div>
      </a> <!-- sieger-item -->
   </div>
  <!-- row -->
  <div class="row">
   <a class="sieger-item" href="products/pit-puzzle-parking-system/"></p>
      <div class="sieger-img">
          <img src="http://192.168.1.156/sieger-parking/wp-content/themes/seiger/theme/img/pit-puzzle-parking.jpg" alt="Pit puzzle parking" />
        </div>
        <div class="siger-txt">
            <p>PIT PUZZLE PARKING SYSTEM</p> 
        </div>
     </a> <!-- sieger-item -->
     <a class="sieger-item" href="products/fully-automated-parking-system/"></p>
        <div class="sieger-img">
           <img src="http://192.168.1.156/sieger-parking/wp-content/themes/seiger/theme/img/fully-automated-parking.jpg" alt="fully automated parking" />
        </div>
     <div class="siger-txt">
        <p>FULLY AUTOMATED PARKING SYSTEM</p>
      </div>
     </a> <!-- sieger-item -->
  </div>
</div>
</h1> 
</div> <!-- Slide Background -->
      <img src="http://192.168.1.156/sieger-parking/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/banner-1.jpg" alt=""  class="img-fluid"/>
      <!--<div class="bs-slider-overlay"></div>-->
    </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <!-- Slide Text Layer -->
         <div class="slide-text slide_style_left">
             <h1 data-animation="animated zoomIn" class="animated zoomIn">
          <p><strong>PUZZLE<br> Parking System </strong>Easy check in and check out the cars</p>
            </h1> 
        </div>
      <!-- Slide Background --> 
      <img src="http://floretmedia.net/temp/sieger-parking-v2/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/banner2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      <!--<div class="bs-slider-overlay"></div>-->
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#bootstrap-touch-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#bootstrap-touch-slider" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
 
 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you might need to remove using js otherwise it will not work normally

Answer (score 0):

You can do with only css use [`media-query`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

When the browser window is `995px` wide or less: use  [`display: none;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) to hide it:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 995px) {
    .carousel-inner{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Note! to use `media-query` you must have this `meta` in your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: tell me for more help:)

Comment: He wants to hide the first carousel-item, not the whole carousel.

Comment: so use `.carousel-item` instead use `.carousel-inner` in media query

Comment: Hi sir, I tried this also but entire slider is not displaying i want to hide only first slide how ca i achieve it please help me

Comment: what version of bootstrsp do u use?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 sir

Comment: first slide -- you mean the first image?? (btw I am woman...)

Comment: Hi sir , i have uploded code in jsfiddle please check it.https://jsfiddle.net/anitha_n19/06n5cbom/14/

Comment: do you mean hide the first image??

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to hide only the first item then add these line of code in `Media-query`.

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item:first-child {
   display: none;
 }
```

Comment: I tried this also sir its but entire slider not displaying.

Comment: @Sency This is working fine. create a fiddle or codepen of working carousel with bootstrap, so we can have a closer look to the issue.

Comment: Hi sir,  i have updated my code in jsfiddle  please check it. https://jsfiddle.net/anitha_n19/06n5cbom/14/

Answer (score 0):

If the carousel items are coming via your php script you can exclude that one item in mobile before actually rendering the carousel using WordPress in built function check.

```
    <?php
    $carousel_items_array=[]; //full items here.
    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
        /* Display and echo mobile specific stuff here */
        $carousel_items_array = [] //exclude the first item here.
    }
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap 4 try adding the class `.hidden-sm-down` to the element to hide from tablets and phones or if using Bootstrap 3 use `.hidden-sm hidden-xs` to hide from tablets and phones.